# Default "selection" of a particular tab on launch of app in TabLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-tablayout

I have used TabLayout and ViewPager in my app. I want to change the ActionBar title whenever i swipe the page. I have been able to do so upto some extent. The problem I'm facing is that on the launch of the app, the title that is displayed on the action bar is the title of my app. When i swipe through and back, the title becomes what i assigned (the correct one).

So suppose the title of my app is 'ABC'. On startup of the app, the default action bar title is shown as 'ABC'. When i swipe through and back to tab1, the correct title is shown.

I figured that this is probably because on startup of the app, no Tab is actually 'selected'. Hence, the code doesn't work.

I have also used the setCurrentItem method which does no good in this case as it sets the default page but doesnt actually help 'select' a particular tab.

Here's the snippet of code i used

```
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
    positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            final String[] tabTitles={"Favorites", "Friends", "Nearby"};
            tabLayout.setNextFocusRightId(position);
            setTitle(tabTitles[position]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `public void onPageSelected(int position)` will be called on setup. You need to set your tile for the default selection.

Just call your `setTitile()` method after setting the listener or even before, with the first title or default tab selected title.

Suppose your default(first) title is "Favorites" 
You can just call

```
setTitle("Favorites");
```

As first or last line of your above code.